# Lua PANIC error

Tags: c++, lua

I am creating a Sudoku solver in C++ while implementing Lua scripting for the actual solving of the puzzle. I have created the following Lua code, but get a

> PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (attempt to call a nil value)

error whenever my C++ code reaches the first instance of lua_call. 
When compiling the code in SciTE, I get the following error:

> lua: SudokuSolver.lua:99: 'end' expected (to close 'for' at line 61)
>   near ''

Adding three 'end's to the end of the function that has the for loop at line 61 clears that error, but causes errors in the C++ program. Can someone please look at my Lua and see if there's any syntax errors or other issues which may be causing this? Thank you

CODE

```
-- Table Declaration
SudokuGrid = {}

function RecieveGrid ( _Pos, _Value )
    -- Recives the cell value at _Pos position from C++
    SudokuGrid[_Pos] = _Value
end

function SolveSudoku ( _Pos )
    -- Recursive function which solves the sudoku puzzle
    local iNewValue = 1

    -- If Position is 82+, all cells are solved
    if( _Pos >= 82 ) then
        return true
    end

    -- If Position already has a value
    if( SudokuGrid[_Pos] ~= 0) then
        return SolveSudoku( _Pos + 1 )
    else
        while(true) do
            SudokuGrid[_Pos] = iNewValue
            iNewValue = iNewValue + 1

            -- If the new value of the cell is higher than 9 its not valid
            if( SudokuGrid[_Pos] > 9 ) then
                --Reset value
                SudokuGrid[_Pos] = 0
                return false
            end

            if( IsValid( _Pos ) and SolveSudoku( _Pos + 1 ) ) then
                return true
            end
        end
    end
end

function IsValid ( _Pos )
    -- Calculate Column and Row in Grid
    x = _Pos % 9
    if( x == 0 ) then
        x = 9
    end
    y = math.ceil(_Pos / 9)

    -- Check Rows
    for i=1, 9 do
        CheckVal = ((y - 1)  * 9) + i
        if( CheckVal == _Pos ) then
            -- Do nothing
        else if ( SudokuGrid[_Pos] == SudokuGrid[CheckVal]and SudokuGrid[_Pos] ~= 0 ) then
            return false
        else
            -- Do nothing
        end
    end

    -- Check Columns
    for i=1, 9 do
        CheckVal = ((i - 1) * 9) + x
        if( CheckVal == _Pos ) then
            -- Do nothing
        else if ( SudokuGrid[_Pos] == SudokuGrid[CheckVal] and SudokuGrid[_Pos] ~= 0 ) then
            return false
        else
            -- Do nothing
        end
    end

    -- Check 3X3 Grid
    SquareCol = math.ceil(x/3)
    SquareRow = math.ceil(y/3)
    StartVal = (SquareCol - 1) * 27 + (SquareRow * 3) -2
    for j=0, 2 do
        for i=0, 2 do
            CheckVal = StartVal + i
            if( CheckVal == _Pos ) then
                -- Do nothing
            else if ( SudokuGrid[_Pos] == SudokuGrid[CheckVal] and SudokuGrid[_Pos] ~= 0 ) then
                return false
            else
                -- Do nothing
            end
        end
        StartVal = StartVal + 9
    end

    return true
end

function SendGrid ( _Pos )
    -- Sends the value at _Pos to C++
    return SudokuGrid[_Pos]
end
```

Comment: Perhaps better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax error is in all lines containing `else if`:

```
else if ( SudokuGrid[_Pos] == SudokuGrid[CheckVal]and SudokuGrid[_Pos] ~= 0 ) then
```

In Lua, use `elseif` instead. Using `else if` would need more closing `end`.

```
elseif SudokuGrid[_Pos] == SudokuGrid[CheckVal] and SudokuGrid[_Pos] ~= 0 then
```